# Paste to Multiple Ranges

Tags: excel, vba

Anyone have a macro to paste to multiple ranges in the same sheet?

Trying to get values into every other column'

```
Sub CopySelections()
    Set cellranges = Application.Selection
    Set ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a destination cell", "Where to paste slections?", Type:=8)
    For Each cellrange In cellranges.Areas
        cellrange.Copy ThisRng.Offset(i)
       i = i + cellrange.Rows.CountLarge
    Next cellrange
End Sub
```

Comment: My apologies, I edited my original question

Comment: The text of your question might suggest that you want to select a range e.g. `A1:E10` and that you want to copy it to e.g. `A11:A20,C11:C20,...,I11:I20`. Your code suggests something different like you might select multiple ranges. Could you explain more accurately what it is you need?

Comment: ...and your offset is by row, not by column.   A small example with a screenshot might be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
Sub Add_Spaces()
Dim ICount As Integer
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set Sheet1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Sheet2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Dim IStart As Integer
Dim copyz As Integer
Dim destinationz As Integer

ICount = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
IStart = 1
destinationz = 1
    For copyz = 1 To ICount Step IStart
        Sheet1.Select
        Columns(copyz).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheet2.Select
        Columns(destinationz).Select
        Sheet2.Paste
        destinationz = destinationz + 2
    Next copyz
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]